# php Warning: Missing argument 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in php and i am trying to do work in php 5 so i have called a parametrized function but it  gives me exception "Warning: Missing argument 1" here is my class

```
class EditUser extends DBConn
{

private $id;
function editUser($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    echo $id;
    die;

    $rows =array();
    self::Set_DBConni();
    $mysqli = self::get_Conn();
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users where id ='".$id."' ");

        while($row = $result->fetch_row())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;

        }


        return $rows;

        /* free result set */
        $result->close();

        /* close connection */
        $mysqli->close();

}


 }
```

and this is how i call it

```
include_once('include/classes/edituser.php'); 

$objPage = new EditUser();

$objPage->editUser($_GET['id']);
```

But it shows me warning and that is

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for EditUser::editUser(), called in E:\xampp\htdocs\WaleedWork\claremont\admin\edit_user.php on line 45 and defined in E:\xampp\htdocs\WaleedWork\claremont\admin\include\classes\edituser.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined variable: id in E:\xampp\htdocs\WaleedWork\claremont\admin\include\classes\edituser.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: id in E:\xampp\htdocs\WaleedWork\claremont\admin\include\classes\edituser.php on line 11
```

Kindly tell me what's wrong because i think i am using the right way to call it.

Comment: so `$_GET['id']` is not set. and never trust user input!

Comment: If you are using `$_GET` then you should have an id on your query string like: `http://localhost?id=1` wherein the id is 1

Comment: i have on my query string

Comment: it is basically edit page link on admin side @ChristianMark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `editUser` method is a constructor , you can do just this

`$objPage = new EditUser($_GET['id']);`

Comment: i have noticed people do the down voting here just for fun

Comment: f it helped, please consider marking my answer as the accepted solution by clicking on the green checkmark   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: i tried it says i can only do in first 2 minutes now its 9 minutes :S

Comment: you can do thumbs up too @user2092317

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a class is either `__construct` (PHP 5+) or **the name of the class itself** (legacy style). So your `editUser` method is seen as being the constructor and is called with `new EditUser`, and you're missing the argument there.